# No primary or single unique constructor found for interface UserDetails

Tags: annotations, mockmvc, userdetailsservice

can't understand and find something useful to solve this issue. I'm trying to test controller method with UserService as argument, [this is controller method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2MRe.png), [this is test method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11jDE.png)

I'm trying @WithMockUserDetails and autowiring userDetailsService and use it inside mockMVC.perform(get("/cart").with(user(userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("vs@gmail.com"))).
sql request is working but exception is thrown anyway: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails